# Why is this Javascript RegExp test not working?

Tags: javascript, regex, security

I'm going mental trying to figure out why this doesn't work:

```
function hasOnlyWhitelistedCharacters(string)
{
    var whitelist = RegExp("\\w");
    console.log(whitelist.test(string));
    return whitelist.test(string);
}
```

When I run this string: "wwww?????****<><><"

Into this function, it returns true. Shouldn't it return false? In fact, it seems like no matter what I do it returns true.

These also don't work:

```
var whitelist = RegExp(\w);
var whitelist = /\w/;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/\w/` matches a single identifier character ([0-9a-zA-Z_]) anywhere in the string. To test against the entire string, use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) ("^" and "$") and [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) ("+" or "*", depending on whether you want to allow the empty string). Try `/^\w*$/` or `/^\w+$/`, or test for the strings you don't want with `/\W/`.

```
function hasOnlyWhitelistedCharacters(string)
{
    var whitelist = /^\w*$/;
    console.log(whitelist.test(string));
    return whitelist.test(string);
}
function hasNoBlacklistedCharacters(string)
{
    var blacklist = /\W/;
    console.log(blacklist.test(string));
    return ! blacklist.test(string);
}
```

For a more complex blacklisted character class, you can use a [complemented class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
function hasOnlyWhitelistedCharacters(string)
{
    // match all characters, which must be in the set
    var whitelist = /^[\w\s\u00C0-\uDFFF\uF900-\uFFFF]*$/;
    console.log(whitelist.test(string));
    return whitelist.test(string);
}

function hasNoBlacklistedCharacters(string)
{
    // match one character not in the set
    var blacklist = /[^\w\s\u00C0-\uDFFF\uF900-\uFFFF]/;
    console.log(blacklist.test(string));
    return ! blacklist.test(string);
}
```

Be careful about character encoding when using regular expressions. Actually, be careful about character encoding in any context. Assumptions about encodings could lead to security holes.

Comment: Ultimately, I am trying to white list all unicode characters but forbid any characters that can be used in a script injection attack.

Comment: Are you talking about XSS? You need to do this on the server. Unless you're using server side JS, the above will never be a secure solution.

Comment: +1 for the code! I was just spending earlier today discovering that Javascript doesn't support POSIX-based ways of identifying Unicode characters, and here you have the Unicode range solution that I was realizing I was going to need. Awesome. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var whitelist=/^\w*$/;
```

The `^` forces it to try matching at the beginning of the string. The `$` forces it to match the end. The `*` after `\w` makes it match more than one instance of `\w`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should open a new uestion for this, but does Javascript regex support "punctuation"? As in: RegExp("^\p{Punctuation}]+$");

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to check whether the target string only contains whitelisted characters, you need to specify you want nothing but them. Add a start and end token and repetition to make it work.

> ^\w+$

Comment: Okay, this is getting somewhere. This works except for one problem, which is that it is forbidding unicode characters. I thought \w would allow unicode characters, such as Japanese and Chinese, because of another answer on a related matter I saw on stackoverflow. However, now I see that's wrong. Is there a way to white list unicode characters?

Comment: @ebisudave: which unicode characters? Unicode includes them all.

Answer (score 2):

to match at least one white-listed character in a set of white-listed characters , try this: `^\w+$`

to match at least zero white-listed characters in a set of white-listed characters , try this: `^\w*$`

-
The carat (^) means that the pattern has to be at the beginning of the string, and the dollar sign ($) means that the pattern has to be at the end of the string. By wrapping what you would like to search for in ^$, any non-specified "junk" will force the regex to return false.

To answer your question though:

`\\w` SHOULD return false because you are un-escaping the backslash and turning it into a normal character. You're actually searching for literally "backslash double-u"

`\w` will return true because you are searching for any white-listed character

A quick google search gave me some websites where you can test your regex (if you would like) and they will help provide some feedback:

http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

I'd also like to suggest using a cheat sheet when making regex if you don't have everything memorized

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

It returns true, because first character is character and your regexp tests only that first character is character.
Try `\w+$` if i understood what you want

Comment: Thanks for responding, though RegExp("\\w+") also doesn't seem to work. I think you understand what I'm going for, but just to be clear, I want to fail the test if any character anywhere in the string is not in the whitelist.

Comment: The regexp matches anywhere in the string. The "+" will cause the "\w" to match one or more times, which will still match the sample string.

Answer (score 1):

It return true because `wwww?????**<><><` string have whitelisted characters. You must add beginning and end of the string in this regexp